# Error CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE when calling clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

Tags: opencl

I have built a library that calls many `opencl` kernels. All kernels pass the following:

```
-oclLoadProgSource
-clCreateProgramWithSource
-clBuildProgram
-clCreateKernel
```

The problem is, when I launch one of those kernels using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`, I get the following error : `CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE`

I know that:

- 5 other kernels have been successfully launched before.
- When I use the source code directly (not via the library), I do not face such problem at all, and everything works fine.

Comment: What library? What are the arguments you pass to the each of the steps of the kernel compilations? What is your kernel code? Without some of this information, we can't help at all.

Comment: First, sorry for my english, maybe it is not clear what I meant.
I have a code that create and lunch multiple kernels.
I use such code in either one of the following ways,
1- Use the source code directly.
2- Convert the source code into a lib file, and hence use this lib file.
That what I meant by a library.

I use the following options for the kernel compilation : "-cl-opt-disable"
I can not provide my kernel code, but maybe it is enough to tell that it is working correctly when I use the source code direclty, not via my built library.

Comment: What is your platform?  How do you convert the source code to a lib file?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2008 on windows 7. I simply built a lib file from my source code - or i do not understand your question.

Comment: And sorry, as i'm new in this

Answer (score 2):

You should test the status returned by **clBuildProgram**. When it fails, get the compiler diagnostics with **clGetProgramBuildInfo(...,CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,...)**.